# Anime with a main character who has a green little friend from another dimension

Tags: story-identification, anime

Does any one knows the anime where the main character has a green little friend from another dimension? He and his friend fuse by joining hands.

It's like his buddy and he join bodies and then he has green armor on the main character.

There is one more step I remember his green little friend is small size on Earth but when they travel in another world he changes size to a large one.

They fuse like Goku and Vegeta but in this case his friend becomes an armor on him and gives him lots of power.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: I immediately thought of [The Great Gazoo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Great_Gazoo), but I know that's not right.

Comment: This is clear what it’s askibg, but too broad

Comment: #Stromblessed  u know the anime what I want?

Comment: @EDITORMUNDA no, what he meant is the close reason is wrong. It's clear you're looking for an anime, but there are too many which could fit your current description. Please [edit] your question with the guidelines provided above :)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a bit like *Comet Lucifer*, which aired in 2015. In it, the main character Sougo comes across a small green creature named Moura, who is able to transform into a large greenish mecha that Sougo can pilot. I don't recall whether this involves them "fusing" like you remember, though, and while there is *sort of* another world in *Comet Lucifer*, I don't believe they ever travel to it.

This is Moura (she doesn't really have hands, though, just stubby little arms):

[image: Moura]

This is her in mecha form:

[image]

Comment: No man it's not the one it's like that it's animation looks like DBZ and Pokemon and the hero of this anime have blonde hair and he is kid from school wo have a little buddy like robo and when he travel to another world through an hole created by some kind of device hero have r I think that device was given by that friend of his and on earth he is just looking like robo but when he got through that hole he look like a green Pokémon for

Comment: @EDITORMUNDA You should edit that information into the question, it'll help anyone who sees your question in the future.